# Can Any one Give me an working example for JSONP in JQuery?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery, jsonp

I Want to Get JSON Data from a web service that is hosted on another server. i tried several examples that is posted in stackoverflow but nothing works. can any one please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "nothing works" is such a wonderfully useful diagnostic. I'll guess that the problem is due to that little bug you squashed on the monitor last week, causing a ray of light from the LCD to refract into an optical input on your ISP's fibre head-end, causing corrupting of some tcp packets containing your JSON request.

Comment: You shouldnt try examples hosted on stackoverflow. You should examples of jQuery.com instead :)

Answer (score 1):

To learn more about jsonp and how to use it properly, I suggest that you check out this video tutorial and the provided sample files:

http://tutsplus.com/lesson/the-twitter-api/

The tutorial uses the twitter API to illustrate how to request data using jsonp. Additionally, if you want to learn more about jQuery in general, you should check out this entire series of video tutorials:

**tutsplus - 30 days to learn jquery**
http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

The tutorials are well made and free of charge compliments of tutsplus.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get JSON data from a server on a different domain, it has to be JSONP data.

The difference is that JSONP returns the JSON data inside a function call, for example:

```
callback({"status":"ok"})
```

Comment: @Jashwant: I saw the title of the question.